# Use ggplots from separate project in R shiny: save and modify later

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, dataformat

I created a large project including a number of complex ggplots. Some of them should be shared using the `shiny` package.

In the `shiny` project I want to add additional data points that are conditional to some widgets in the sidebarPanel.

My question is if there is a way to save ggplots so that they can be modified in another project (that is adding `+geom_point()`) without using the original data or code that was used to create the plot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just gave the ggplot object in an RDS file. For example

```
# create sample plot
library(ggplot2)
dd <- data.frame(x=1:10, y=exp(1:10))
gg <- ggplot(dd, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()

# save it and delete it from workspace
saveRDS(gg, "plot.rds")
rm(gg)

#reload it (into new object) and add layer
g2 <- readRDS("plot.rds")
g2 + geom_line()
```

Comment: Thanks so much - that did it!